# Loading async data from property setter

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm not sure what is the best method to load async data when a bound property changes.

I have a ListView and when an item is selected I display new content with a detailed data. The detail item is obtained from an async method.

Data method:

```
private async void ShowDetailAsync()
{
  if (SelectedItem?.Id != null)
  {
    detailViewModel.Item = await storage.GetDetailItemAsync(SelectedItem.Id);
  }
  else
  {
    detailViewModel.Item = null;
  }
}
```

ViewModel property:

```
public GearItemListViewModel SelectedItem 
{
  get => selectedItem; 
  set { this.SetValue(ref selectedItem, value); ShowDetailAsync(); } 
}
```

Now it works as fire-and-forget async method, but how would it be the best approach to load it without risk of desynchronized view and data when user rapidly browses the records in the ListView (first click takes longer to load the record than the other)?

Or is there another method how to switch and load detail items, without async call in the property setter?

Comment: You may take a look [at Stephen Cleary's blog](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-3-properties.html) and his [post at magazine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to use the "asynchronous property" approach described in my [MSDN article on async data binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

In this case, your `detailViewModel.Item` property would change type from `TItem` to [`NotifyTask<TItem>`](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/Nito.Mvvm.Async/1.0.0-pre-01/netstandard1.0/doc/Nito.Mvvm.NotifyTask'1), and your `ShowDetailAsync` becomes:

```
private void ShowDetail()
{
  if (SelectedItem?.Id != null)
  {
    detailViewModel.Item = NotifyTask.Create(storage.GetDetailItemAsync(SelectedItem.Id);
  }
  else
  {
    detailViewModel.Item = null;
  }
}
```

Note that the method is synchronous. It is synchronously starting an asynchronous operation.

With this change, your data binding would need to update to reference `Item.Result` instead of `Item`. You can then data bind to other properties such as `Item.IsNotCompleted` if you want to show a spinner/loading indicator, and `Item.IsFaulted` to notify the user of an error (with the previous `async void` approach, any errors would be raised directly on the UI thread).

Comment: Thanks. How would I assign an empty viewmodel (not coming from async service method)?
Is this ok?
    detailViewModel.Item = new NotifyTaskCompletion<GearItemDetailViewModel>(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => new GearItemDetailViewModel()));

or better Task.FromResult(new GearItemDetailViewModel());

Comment: You should use `FromResult` then. It's fairly odd to have to do that, though.

Comment: Has anyone tried it with {x:Bind}? When I use static two-way binding, I get null reference exception when leaving target textbox and the source is being updated. The Item is assigned new NotifyTask, so Result is null and after that binding system tries to update source (ViewModel.Item.Result...). Dynamic binding works fine.

Comment: I have not tried it with `{x:Bind}`. If you do need a "stub" value while the operation is in progress, then you can pass a `TItem` as the second parameter of `NotifyTask.Create`. Though IMO it would be better to disable those controls if it's in the process of changing anyway.

Comment: Disabling the control doesn't help. It's not that the user clicks or edits textboxes during selected item switch. I just place cursor in the textbox and click in the list on the other item and it crashes because textbox lost focus and tried to update the source, which has new Item instance and the result is not yet available. The problem is the order of events of textbox focus loss and listview item selection change. Currently I have no workaround for this (other than using dynamic binding).